# Django,NOT NULL constraint failed: main_app_staff.course_id

Tags: python, django

I'm copying a project on GiHub, the code is following:

models:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
   #some info need to submit


class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
class Staff(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    admin = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.admin.last_name + " " + self.admin.first_name
'''
views.py:
'''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            first_name = form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
            last_name = form.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
            address = form.cleaned_data.get('address')
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            gender = form.cleaned_data.get('gender')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            course = form.cleaned_data.get('course')
            passport = request.FILES.get('profile_pic')
            fs = FileSystemStorage()
            filename = fs.save(passport.name, passport)
            passport_url = fs.url(filename)
            try:
                user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(
    email=email,password=password,user_type=2,first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name,profile_pic = passport_url
                )
                user.gender=gender
                user.address=address
                user.save()
                staff = Staff(course = Course.objects.get(name=course),admin = user)
                staff.save()
                messages.success(request,"Successfully Added")
                return redirect(reverse("add_staff"))
            except Exception as e:
                messages.error(request, "Could Not Add " + str(e))
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Please fulfil all requirements")
    return render(request,"hod_template/add_staff_template.html",context)
```

But when I debug it, it's continuing noting me "NOT NULL constraint failed: `main_app_staff.course_id"`， I'm not sure if I need to create a Staff object.

I don't know how to solve it .... please

Here is the whole traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "A:\Anaconda\envs\task1.25\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "A:\Anaconda\envs\task1.25\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: main_app_staff.course_id
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\15295\Desktop\task-1.25\student_management_system\main_app\hod_views.py", line 73, in add_staff
    user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(
  File "C:\Users\15295\Desktop\task-1.25\student_management_system\main_app\models.py", line 17, in create_user
    return self._create_user(email,password,**extra_fields)
  File "C:\Users\15295\Desktop\task-1.25\student_management_system\main_app\models.py", line 12, in _create_user
    user.save(using=self._db)
  File "A:\Anaconda\envs\task1.25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 67, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "A:\Anaconda\envs\task1.25\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 753, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "A:\Anaconda\envs\task1.25\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 801, in save_base
    post_save.send(
  File "A:\Anaconda\envs\task1.25\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 177, in send
    return [
  File "A:\Anaconda\envs\task1.25\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 178, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "C:\Users\15295\Desktop\task-1.25\student_management_system\main_app\models.py", line 162, in create_user_profile
    Staff.objects.create(admin=instance)
  File "A:\Anaconda\envs\task1.25\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "A:\Anaconda\envs\task1.25\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 447, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "A:\Anaconda\envs\task1.25\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 753, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "A:\Anaconda\envs\task1.25\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 790, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "A:\Anaconda\envs\task1.25\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 895, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "A:\Anaconda\envs\task1.25\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 933, in _do_insert
  File "A:\Anaconda\envs\task1.25\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "A:\Anaconda\envs\task1.25\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "A:\Anaconda\envs\task1.25\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: main_app_staff.course_id
```

Comment: Please, share the full traceback. Normally the Django error page has a function to turn the error in a text format that includes settings, traceback, etc.

Comment: sorry,there isnt any traceback.... just  a template with the error message